# Upload File With JavaScript and REST API from Azure Storage for PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am working with the Azure Storage API, I have my URL with SAS, as well as the code that captures is the photo, audio or video of my phone with PhoneGap.

When the phone stores the photo, audio, video... gives me a route.

I have the local file on my device, the question is... how it should be uploaded my file?
Bytes, base64... was looking for documentation in this regard, but can not find.

Annex code that I am using to upload the file, not is if it is the right thing.
My question is "data" which should be

```
$.ajax({
            url: uri,
            type: "PUT",
            data: requestData,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
            },
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(desc);
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The data should be in `bytes`. Not sure if you can use HTML 5's `File API`, but if you do you can simply use that to read the file contents as array buffer and then convert it into unsigned int array and pass that to your upload routine. Here's a sample code to do so from this blog post: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileContent = selectedFile.slice(currentFilePointer, currentFilePointer + maxBlockSize);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);

reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        var uri = submitUri + '&comp=block&blockid=' + blockIds[blockIds.length - 1];
        var requestData = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            type: "PUT",
            data: requestData,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);
            },
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                bytesUploaded += requestData.length;
                var percentComplete = ((parseFloat(bytesUploaded) / parseFloat(selectedFile.size)) * 100).toFixed(2);
                $("#fileUploadProgress").text(percentComplete + " %");
                uploadFileInBlocks();
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(desc);
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

One important thing to remember is to se `processData` flag in ajax request to `false` (default is `true`) otherwise the data will be corrupted.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I do not use HTML5 Api. It had already reviewed your article before, but as I don't use that... I don't understand very well. In addition I'm not good with English lol